# Не подсвечиваются не заполненные поля в форме

Tags: javascript, html

Есть поле ввода, где все 5 полей ввода обязательные. При нажатии на кнопку, не всплывают подсказки, что необходимо заполнить поле.

```js
function submitForm(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // Получаем значения полей формы
  var brandd = document.getElementById("brandd").value;
  var modell = document.getElementById("modell").value;
  var yearr = document.getElementById("yearr").value;
  var mileagee = document.getElementById("mileagee").value;
  var messagee = document.getElementById("messagee").value;

  // Сохраняем ответ в списке ответов
  var response = brandd + " - " + modell + " - " + yearr + " - " + mileagee + " - " + messagee;
  // var responsesList = document.getElementById("responses");
  // var listItem = document.createElement("li");
  // listItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(response));
  // responsesList.appendChild(listItem);

  document.getElementById("loading-screen").style.display = "block";

  // отпраляем запрос на сервер с нейронкой
  fetch(`${SERVER_ADDR}completion?brand=${brandd}&model=${modell}&year=${yearr}&mileage=${mileagee}&problem=${messagee}`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
      }
    })
    // обрабатываем данные с нейронки
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      if (data.result === "Не все поля были заполнены") {
        document.getElementById("loading-screen").style.display = "none";
        return;
      }

      // Показываем второе окно
      var feedbackForm = document.getElementById("feedback-form-o");
      var responseList = document.getElementById("response-list");
      feedbackForm.classList.add("hidden");
      responseList.classList.remove("hidden");

      document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = data.result;

      document.getElementById("loading-screen").style.display = "none";
    })
}
```

```html
<form class="login-form" style="z-index: 1;">
  <div class="row position-relative overback" style="z-index: 1; ">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <div class="form-icon position-relative">
          <input type="text" id="brandd" class="form-control ps-3  pt-15 pb-15" placeholder="Марка" required>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <div class="form-icon position-relative">
          <input type="text" id="modell" class="form-control ps-3  pt-15 pb-15" placeholder="Модель" required>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <div class="form-icon position-relative">
          <input type="phone" id="yearr" class="form-control ps-3  pt-15 pb-15" placeholder="Год выпуска" required>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <div class="form-icon position-relative">
          <input type="phone" id="mileagee" class="form-control ps-3  pt-15 pb-15" placeholder="Пробег" required>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <div class="form-icon position-relative">
          <textarea name="comments" id="messagee" rows="3" class="form-control ps-3" placeholder="Опишите вашу проблему" required></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 my-3">
      <div class=" text-center">
        <input type="submit" value="Отправить" class="text-stoblue m-0 py-3 px-5 btn btn-white" onclick="submitForm(event)">
        <!-- <button type="submit" id="submit" name="send" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submitForm(event)">Отправить</button> -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Снова гадать.. Что происходит в функции `submitForm()`?

Comment: Ну, я не думал, что это важно)

Comment: Вангую. функция прежде, чем отправить собственно форму, должна проверить, заполнены ли все обязательные поля, и если нет, то и вовсе не отправлять форму, а выделить поля и дать сообщения об ошибках.

Comment: Но без без вызова функции, каждое незаполненное поле подсвечивалось, после же - перестало.

Comment: Вообще-то атрибут `required` работает. О том, что поле необходимо заполнить - сообщение есть.

Comment: Проверял на работе с нескольких компов - ничего не показывается, кроме анимации, которая должна идти после отправки запроса.

Comment: Так вы сами запретили отображение системных сообщений о не заполненных полях: event.preventDefault(); Закомментируйте эту строку и проверьте работу формы ещё раз.